# limit of square root of sum

Tags: calculus, limits

Hi I made it to my last problem in this section and I'm stumped at how to solve this:

$$\lim_{x\to -1} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+8}-3}{x+1}$$

I use the x-value that we are approaching as a hint.. and the denominator shows me I know that: $$x\neq-1$$

Do I need to see if $(x+1)$ is a factor of the top somehow? I feel like I'm missing something... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

The numerator doesn't factor into the denominator, so the trick here is to multiply by the conjugate, i.e.

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+8}-3}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+8}-3}{x+1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2+8}+3}{\sqrt{x^2+8}+3}=\ldots$$

Comment: Ah, so when that happens, is that my queue to always try to multiply by the conjugate? or are there other things to check first?

Comment: Yes, it often helps in these kind of problems to multiply by the conjugate. @Adam

Comment: very useful tip. as a first course of action, after remembering to avoid divide by zero, go for attempting to multiply by the conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+8}-3}{x+1}=\frac{x^2+8-9}{(x+1)(\sqrt{x^2+8}+3)}=\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2+8}+3}$$  if $x+1\ne0$

Here as $x\to-1,x+1\to0\implies x+1\ne0$